# How to call a set of variables functions based on class on a group of elements

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, raphael

I have the following html code:

```
<i class="small ele class1"></i>
<i class="medium ele class1"></i>
<i class="large ele class1"></i>

<div class="clear"></div>

<i class="small ele class2"></i>
<i class="medium ele class2"></i>
<i class="large ele class2"></i>

<div class="clear"></div>

<i class="small ele class3"></i>
<i class="medium ele class3"></i>
<i class="large ele class3"></i>

<div class="clear"></div>

<i class="small ele class4"></i>
<i class="medium ele class4"></i>
<i class="large ele class4"></i>​
```

And my javascript looks like so:

```
var resize = function(face, s) {
    var bb = face.getBBox();
    console.log(bb);
    var w = bb.width;
    var h = bb.height;
    var max = w;
    if (h > max) {
        max = h;
    }
    var scale = s / max;
    var ox = -bb.x+((max-w)/2);
    var oy = -bb.y+((max-h)/2);

    console.log(s+' '+h+' '+bb.y);

    face.attr({
        "transform": "s" + scale + "," + scale + ",0,0" + "t" + ox + "," + oy 
    });

}

$('.ele').each(function() {
    var s = $(this).innerWidth();
    var paper = Raphael($(this)[0], s, s);

    var face = $(this).hasClass("class1") ? class1Generator(paper) : class4Generator(paper);


    /*switch (true) {
        case $(this).hasClass('class1'):
            class1Generator(paper);
        break;

        case $(this).hasClass('class2'):
            class2Generator(paper)  
            break;

        case $(this).hasClass('class3'):
            class3Generator(paper)    
            break;

        case $(this).hasClass('class4'):
            class4Generator(paper)
            break;
    }*/


    resize(face, s);

});
```

my question is, how could I make this line of code more scalable? I tried using a switch but 
The script below is calling two functions if one of the elements has a class, but what If i have 10 classes?
I don't think is the best solution I created a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7uUgz/6/

```
    //var face = $(this).hasClass("awesome") ? awesomeGenerator(paper) : awfulGenerator(paper);
```

Comment: if your code is working and you just want to improve it, should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uUgz/8/)

Basically it extracts the number from the 'class#' and calls the appropriate function.

```
$('.ele').each(function() {
    var s = $(this).innerWidth();
    var paper = Raphael($(this)[0], s, s);
    var id = 0;


    var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    $.each(classList, function(index, item) {
        if (item.indexOf('class') != -1) {
            id = item.replace('class', '');
            console.log('id : ' + id);
        }
    });

    var face = eval('class' + id + 'Generator')(paper);
    resize(face, s);

});
```

Instead of using class1, class2 ..., you could just use a data attribute and read that when you need to call the function..

Something like:

```
<i data-id="1" class="small ele class1"></i>
```

And why are you using `<i>` elements?

Comment: My bad, when I posted the last line, it didn't show the <i>. Now my phrase makes more sense.

Comment: I am basically creating a family of icons, something similar to http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/ and I think makes sense to  do <i class="arrow small"><i> instead of <span class="arrow small"></span> just like they do :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using `eval()` you can bind some custom events to the generation classes.

```
$(".class1").bind("generate", function(paper)
{
  ...
});
$(".class2").bind("generate", function(paper)
{
  ...
});

$(".ele").trigger("generate");
```

Comment: Smart! I like it. My answer used eval() but it's usually something I try to avoid!